# Migration, Schema and the DRY principle

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm new to Elixir and Ecto, and wander wheather we break the DRY principle by declaring the schema of an object twice: both as a migration and as a schema.

I assume the migration of a table creation could be the default schema, couldn't it?

Comment: They serve different purposes, plus the default schema does not declare keys, foreign keys etc. Embedded schema might be stored in the DB in different ways. Migration might _modify_ a schema. Etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, actually it would be super weird to try to make one file to do everything.
Ecto's schemas handle the belongs_to/has_many/many_to_many relationships, and the migration, well… handles the "talking to the database" part. :)

Comment: This should be a comment, no an answer.

Comment: ">you must have 50 reputation to comment." 

Make it happen and I shall be able to do that ;)